# How to fix specific XSS issues in URL via php?

Tags: php, xss

I am using Netsparker community edition for checking my app for any general security holes.  I'm getting a lot of following XSS probable issue areas:

```
my_php_file.php?nsextt=" stYle=x:expre/**/ssion(alert(9)) ns="
```

Code in my_php_file.php is not accepting any `$_GET` or `$_POST` parameters.

So how I am supposed to fix this sort of XSS problems if I'm not even using those `$_GET` or `$_POST` parameters?

Also in pages where I do use `$_GET` params I get this:

```
my_php_file2.php?id=" stYle=x:expre/**/ssion(alert(9)) ns="
```

I do filter all incoming params (for example id from last snippet):

```
trim(htmlspecialchars($_GET['id']));
```

And after all that I even run result of previous in preg to allow only digits in that id param.

Could someone would so kind and advise me what those XSS alerts are all about? How to approach them?

Comment: strip_tags does not filter ". Please note that expression() only works on Internet Explorer. But in this case you can use **1" onmouseover="alert('XSS');** for cross browser compatibility.

Comment: Are you using the `REQUEST_URI` server variable? Putting that unescaped in a form action is a common error.

Comment: @bobince i do not use `REQUEST_URI` at form action, but i do use it it in my functions file that i use it for manipulating current URL http://pastebin.com/Mzrfjj7F

Comment: Don't encode/filter incoming data, encode it where it is used. That's the only point where you can know what kind of encoding is required.

Comment: @arma: then you would have to use `htmlspecialchars()` on anywhere you used the output of that function. Indeed, as per DW's answer, you should in any case be using `htmlspecialchars()` any time you put text content into HTML output, rather than trying to handle at the input stage.

Comment: @bobince yep rewrote that function with support to `htmlspecialchars()` and other checks. Now it looks like automated tests don't report any XSS issues anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you read about defending against XSS.  OWASP has good resources.  You need to apply proper input validation to all input values, and properly escape all dynamic values that you insert into the output HTML document.  There are many online resources on how to prevent XSS.

As far as your specific application, you haven't provided us enough information to diagnose the issue.  Did you try opening `my_php_file.php?nsextt="..."` in your browser, to see what happens?  Does an alert dialog pop up?  If you view the source of the response, do you see a "`style=...`" attribute anywhere in the response?  Also, though you say you don't use any GET parameters in my_php_file.php, is it possible that code in my_php_file.php might include another PHP file or might call some other function that produces unsafe output?  I suspect you may have an XSS vulnerability that allows injection of a new attribute into the middle of some attribute list somewhere.

You mention the approach you are using to sanitize the parameters on other pages.  I'd like to mention that this is not the proper input sanitization method.  `strip_tags` does not prevent XSS (`strip_tags` is not guaranteed to remove all tags; and even if it did, removing all tags is not sufficient, as one can still mount an XSS attack by injecting attributes without injecting any new tags).  A good rule of thumb is that if you're using `strip_tags`, you're probably doing something wrong.

More generally, input validation is not about blindly throwing every stripping function you can think of the data.  Instead, you should check that the input matches a suitable whitelist or regexp, as appropriate for the type of the data.   And, when you output the data, you should escape it  in a way that is suitable for the context where the data will be inserted.  For instance, if you are inserting it into the standard between-tag HTML context, you can escape the data with `htmlescapechars`.  If you are inserting it as a link (as the value of a href attribute), then you need to ensure that it is a properly formatted URL with a safe scheme (http or https are safe; javascript is not).  There's a lot more to say about input validation and output escaping: see the OWASP resources for a lot of great information on this topic.

Comment: About data sanitization i totally agree and i should review my app with more careful sanitize. But anyways at the end i still do hard preg check only for digits 0-9 only, if it's something else it won't accept it. Theres no single user input in my script that is not filtered. I'm more leaning to the part where i have made some XSS ways via my own code - for example check @cx42net comment i made.

Comment: +1 for input validation clarification. strip_tags is useless and HTML-escaping at the input stage is very the wrong thing.

Answer (score 5):

For your first question, if you sure about your code not using $_GET or $_POST, then you should be fine. But are you using a framework or some other code ?
Have you tried to access `my_php_file.php?nsextt=hello%20world` and search for "hello world" in the source? Maybe you forget some include that use $_GET['nsextt'] ?

(note : by passing var via the url in a browser, only $_GET will be used.)

Now, for the second part, instead of all those functions + preg to check if the input is an int, you should use the [`filter_var()`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php) functions in php :

```
$secure_integer = filter_var($_GET['id'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

If you want, you can also just validate the input with `FILTER_VALIDATE_INT` instead of `FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out filter_var function. I use custom made cms. If i run any of XSS example stuff in my URL it will add to language switcher links. Was before - `register.php?lang=en`, after - `register.php?lang=en&nsextt=hello world`.

I made that so i can switch languages and stay on same page where user was before (for example this: `register.php?lang=en&page=123`).

Comment: I understand, but does nsextt have an impact in your resulting html ? (search for the "hello world" string in the source, do you find it ? can you change it via the url?)

Comment: other than that appended part to my language switcher theres no more mention of that string in html.

Comment: As i expected - my language switcher script was not correctly sanitazing data. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

use this library to protect you against XSS attacks [Google Code PHP-antixss](http://code.google.com/p/php-antixss/)
and also  their is a PHP functions called [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)
that will help you a lot and you should know about it ,you can use [OWASP XSS prevention cheat sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) 
as a guide also

Comment: Thanks great to see some nice scripts. For the form data i also use this library: https://svn.liip.ch/repos/public/ext/externalinput/trunk/lx/externalinput/clean.php

Comment: @Bnhack - as per my comment on one of your other questions - you need to post answers, not links to elsewhere. Please feel free to update your answer to improve it.

Comment: you mean this is not an answer ,then how should i answer